# Sleeping in VBA (Integer Overflow!!)

Tags: vba, integer-overflow, kernel32

In VBA you can

`Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

to provide yourself with a sleep routine.

However, the `Long` that must be passed to the routine appears to overflow for values in excess of 32000 milliseconds.

Is there a way to sleep for longer periods of time without the complexity of stringing together several consecutive calls to the sleep routine?

Comment: Does calling `Sleep` in a loop count as "stringing together several consecutive calls"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't overflow, unless your code that calculates required number of milliseconds causes an overflow.

Example:

```
dim t as long
t = 10000 * 10000 / 10000 'Overflow
```

Example 2:

```
dim t as long
t = 10000! * 10000 / 10000 'Ok
```

Comment: You're right.  The issue was only that I failed to specify that my argument was a Long with sufficient explicitness.