# Cross Compatibility of Millisecond Timer Resolution in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007, macos, excel-2011

I would like to get fractional timer resolution in an Excel VBA project that has to be compatible with Windows Excel 2007 and Mac OS Excel 2011. Ive found a method in windows utilizing [`sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930841/sleeping-in-vba-integer-overflow)  from `kernel32.dll` and a method on Mac OS using [`MacScript("GetMilliSec")`](http://www.realgeek.com/forums/timing-vba-execution-305689.html).

I currently have limited access to a Mac, so I am not able to test this out directly right now. If I declare `Sleep` like this:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Will an error be raised when the file is opened in a Mac? Or will the error be flagged only when/if `Sleep` is called in a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll need to use conditional compilation to avoid your API declaration causing an error on a Mac.

```
   #If Mac Then
      MsgBox "I'm a Mac"
   #Else
      MsgBox "I'm a PC"
   #End If
```

Comment: I have seen this code before... is `Mac` something that would be recognized in the Conditional Compilation "code"? It is not feasible for me to distribute a second version of the project to Mac users only, so I couldnt use something `#CONST Mac = True` and then manually change it and redistribute with `#CONST Mac = False`

Comment: @Hari - I'd thought there were some "built-in" conditional compilation constants, but it seems that may not be the case.  I did test my code (without declaring the "Mac" constant) and it appeared to work, but now I see it doesn't error even if you use an undeclared constant - it just gives it a default value of False.

Comment: @Tim... Thanks for your efforts! That gives me what I need to know.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Mac using Office 2011 and can confirm that an error will be raised when the sub calls `sleep` with `File not found: kernel32`

If you have an alternative approach to use the `sleep` command in Mac, please share and use the below logic to select Mac or Windows:

```vb
Public Sub WINorMAC()
'Test for the operating system.
    If Not Application.OperatingSystem Like "*Mac*" Then
        'Is Windows.
        Call Windows_specific_function()
    Else
        'Is a Mac and will test if running Excel 2011 or higher.
        If Val(Application.Version) > 14 Then
            Call Mac_specific_function()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You can also use this code to set a timer with up to 7 decimals, which works for both Mac and Windows:

```vb
'---------TIMER MACRO--------'
'PURPOSE: Determine how many seconds it took for code to completely run
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim minutesElapsed As Double

'Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

'*************************************
'------Start to run code--------'
'*************************************

        Your code goes here


'*************************************
'----------End code----------'
'*************************************


'Determine how many seconds code took to run

'If you want in seconds with two decimals, use this line:
'SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

'If you want with up to 7 decimals, use this line:
SecondsElapsed = Timer - StartTime

'Notify user how long the macro took
If SecondsElapsed > 60 Then
    minutesElapsed = Int(SecondsElapsed / 60)
    SecondsElapsed = Int(SecondsElapsed - (minutesElapsed * 60))

    Msgbox "This code ran successfully in " & minutesElapsed & " minutes and " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

Else
    Msgbox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

End If
```