# Sleep Equivalent for mac in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I want to add a wait block for 500 milliseconds in macOS VBA editor for Excel. I know

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

Works, but this can't go under 1 second. I have tried the sleep command too:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
...
Sleep 500
```

But this gives me an error saying

```
File Not Found "kernel32"
```

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Does [Cross Compatibility of Millisecond Timer Resolution in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246526/cross-compatibility-of-millisecond-timer-resolution-in-excel-vba) help?

Comment: From what I understood, it does outline a way to time how long your code took to execute, but I want to add a slight 500 milliseconds delay to my code rather than count how long it takes. Please correct me if I'm wrong, thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Excel on a Mac, but some of the answers to [AppleScript “delay” command not working since switch to Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161749/applescript-delay-command-not-working-since-switch-to-yosemite) look like they could be useful.

Answer (score 3):

This will work on both Windows and Mac:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Private Declare  Sub MSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #End If
#End If

Public Sub Sleep(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#If Mac Then
    USleep dwMilliseconds * 1000&
#Else
    MSleep dwMilliseconds
#End If
End Sub
```

### Edit #1

The following code fixes overflow issues for Mac:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #End If
#End If

#If Mac Then
Public Sub Sleep(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    If dwMilliseconds And &H80000000 Then
        USleep &HFFFFFFFF
    ElseIf dwMilliseconds > &H418937 Then
        USleep &HFFFFFFFF
    ElseIf dwMilliseconds > &H20C49B Then
        USleep (dwMilliseconds * 500& Or &H80000000) * 2&
    Else
        USleep dwMilliseconds * 1000&
    End If
End Sub
#End If
```

### Edit #2

With the help of [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12287457/gwd), the Mac `Sleep` now behaves exactly as the Windows counterpart:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #End If
#End If

#If Mac Then
Public Sub Sleep(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Const maxMicro As Long = &HFFFFFED8  'unsigned &HFFFFFFFF divided by 1000 is not round
    Const maxMilli As Long = &H418937    'unsigned &HFFFFFED8 divided by 1000
    Const maxMilliPos As Long = maxMilli \ 2 '&H20C49B
    Const signBit As Long = &H80000000
    Const maxMilliNeg As Long = maxMilli Or signBit
    '
    Do While dwMilliseconds And signBit
        USleep maxMicro
        If dwMilliseconds < maxMilliNeg Then
            dwMilliseconds = (dwMilliseconds Xor signBit) - maxMilli Xor signBit
        Else
            dwMilliseconds = dwMilliseconds - maxMilli
        End If
    Loop
    Do While dwMilliseconds > maxMilli
        USleep maxMicro
        dwMilliseconds = dwMilliseconds - maxMilli
    Loop
    If dwMilliseconds > maxMilliPos Then
        USleep (dwMilliseconds * 500& Or signBit) * 2&
    Else
        USleep dwMilliseconds * 1000&
    End If
End Sub
#End If
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code block above will work with one small addition. Simply divide the TimeValue by 2 to get 500ms

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") / 2)
```